# trouble saving data from nested attributes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I am having an absolute nightmare trying to get these models to save. The parent model is called Galleries and the child is exhibition images. The form is nested. When I attempt to update the attributes in the form, they are not saved. I am not sure exactly where the problem is. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
  end

  def create
  end

  def update
    @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]
    if @gallery.save(gallery_params)
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      render '/new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]
    @image = 3.times { @gallery.exhibition_images.new }
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def index
    @gallery = Gallery.all
  end

  def show
  end

  private 

    def gallery_params
      params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, :id, exhibition_images_attributes: [:image, :id])
    end

end
```

Gallery Model

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
    belongs_to :guide
    has_many :exhibition_images
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :exhibition_images
end
```

Exhibition Images

```
class ExhibitionImage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :gallery

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "100x100", guide: "500x500" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

end
```

edit.html.erb

```
   <h1>Galleries#edit</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/galleries/edit.html.erb</p>
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@gallery, :html => {:multipart => true}, layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-2", control_col: "col-sm-10") do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>    

<%= f.fields_for :exhibition_images do |x| %>
    <%= x.file_field :image, help: "Ensure images are minimum 400x400px"  %>

    <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Create/Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

log from attempted update

```
    Started PATCH "/galleries/david-knight-maurizio-miele-anita-rowell-a-triangle-of-modern-art" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-01 13:25:18 +0100
Processing by GalleriesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JzFnQgV4ZBoh176xdphPtH/AJsm/BE1N+LWtTUTOgx8=", "gallery"=>{"title"=>"FRED FRED", "exhibition_images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000102781b00 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/ns/ry6z7jfd6qg6j8xr2q6dw0yc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20140701-29180-17bovdo>, @original_filename="mag.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gallery[exhibition_images_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"mag.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}}}, "commit"=>"Create/Update", "id"=>"david-knight-maurizio-miele-anita-rowell-a-triangle-of-modern-art"}
```

update:

schema.rb

```
create_table "exhibition_images", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "gallery_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "galleries", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.integer  "guide_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "guides", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "date_starting"
    t.datetime "date_ending"
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.string   "image_extra_file_name"
    t.string   "image_extra_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_extra_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_extra_updated_at"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.text     "extra_info"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "slug"
  end

  add_index "guides", ["slug"], name: "index_guides_on_slug", using: :btree

  create_table "images", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "gallery_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Comment: Provide a better description WHAT is wrong with your output, what you have tried, and what exactly doesn't work

Comment: @23tux there is no output, when i try to update the attributes they are not being saved

Comment: No errors in the console? You further debug this by checking if validations are failing,  and/or put a before save and see if the callback is getting called.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong initially. Might not be the problem, but you have an id in your `gallery_params` method.

Comment: Can you post your schema?

Comment: @DickieBoy, added schema

Comment: @AlokSwain, i did what you said and it worked....     gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]

    respond_to do |format|
      if gallery.update(gallery_params)
        format.html { redirect_to gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: gallery }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

I dont know why though?