# nested attributes form, image not being saved RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nested-attributes

i have an edit form in which a user can add images. the form belongs to the 'Gallery' model, the images are the child model 'Exhibition images'. I can edit the title as it belongs to the parent model, however the images I attach are coming up as nil (if I display them without the rails image_tag i get something like this ExhibitionImage id: 1, image_file_name: nil, image_content_type: nil, image_file_size: nil, image_updated_at: nil, gallery_id: 8, created_at:). I imagine its my implementation of nested forms, which I dont quite understand.

Hereis the relevant code:

GALLERY CONTROLLER

```
def update
    @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @gallery.update(gallery_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gallery }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]
    @image = @gallery.exhibition_images.new
  end
```

GALLERY MODEL

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
    belongs_to :guide
  has_many :exhibition_images, :autosave => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :exhibition_images
end
```

EXHIBITION IMAGE

```
class ExhibitionImage < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :gallery, :autosave => true

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "100x100", guide: "500x500" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

end
```

EDIT FORM

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@gallery, :html => {:multipart => true}, layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-2", control_col: "col-sm-10") do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>    

<%= f.fields_for :exhibition_images do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :image, help: "Ensure images are minimum 400x400px"  %>

    <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Create/Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

How do I get the attached images to save into the db!?

Comment: I wonder why you asked this question if you already had it correctly in this question of yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510280/trouble-saving-data-from-nested-attributes-in-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I needed to add this line to my params methods

```
  params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, exhibition_images_attributes: [:image])
```

'exhibition_images_attributes' instead of the model attribute. Not sure why, but it worked.

Comment: because it is a nested child model.  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters may help you.